# About gVim and Jetbrains Mono: How to stop gVIM to render text like (==, !=) in special way

Tags: vim, fonts

I am using `JetBrains Mono`, but some text are rendered hard to recognize.
In terminal, all looks fine:
[image]

But if I open it in gVim, it will be:
[image]

Sometimes, the `=` does not disp at all
[image]

In gVim:
[image]

If I use default font `Monospace`, there is no such problem. Does it depend on the font? How do I fix it?

Comment: FWIW, `gvimrc` is only sourced in a GUI version of Vim, i.e. not in terminal. See `:help gvimrc`. Even if it were, `guifont` is an option only for the GUI version as shown in `:help 'guifont'`. It looks fine in terminal because your changes don't apply there.

Comment: `:verbose set guiligatures?`

Comment: @Friedrich Thx. I give image about terminal in order to only to show what exactly the text is.

Comment: It's a good thing you show the actual code (btw, [you should not post images of code]((//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)). I misunderstood "in terminal" to mean "in non-GUI Vim" when reading the question first. Wanted to make it clear.

Comment: @Matt Thx. Got `Unknown option guiligatures`.

Comment: `guiligatures` is only available in gVim, so please run it again in gVim where your problems are

Comment: Option [`'guiligatures'`](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/4eeedc09fed0cbbb3ba48317e0a01e20cd0b4f80) was added in Vim 8.2.3524 and only for GTK GUI.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I do mean gVim, but my Vim version was 7.4.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that vim 7.4 has no options about ligatures. I downloaded JetBrainsMono font without ligatures. Usually these fonts end with "NL" in their name, such as `JetBrainsMono NL`.